# Redux selector on many to many

Tags: reactjs, redux

React + Redux recommend saving data normalized and using selectors to get derived data. So in our store we save `Users` and `Tags` which have a many to many relationship.

```
type Store = {
    entities: {
        users: User[];
        tags: Tag[];
        userTagMapping: { userId: string, tagId: string }[]
    }
}
```

And in our view we want to show some derived data for this many to many relation-ship. For example we want to calculate the total users with some tag or the online-users with some tag. Right now we solved this using [rselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). The only problem is that calculating these things becomes quite tedious. For example we have a selector which returns a map from a tag-id to a list of users to show which users belong to this tag (and vice versa a selector from user-id to tag list).

```
const selectUsersPerTag = createSelector(
    selectUsers, selectTags, selectUserTagMapping,
    (users, tags, mapping) => {
        let result = {};
        for (const tag on tags) {
             const isUserMappedToTag = user => ({userId, tagId}) => userId == user.id && tagId === tag.id
             result[tag.id] = users.filter(user => mapping.some(isUserMappedToTag(user)))
        }
        return result
    }
)
```

and in my opinion this looks quite ugly and is a bit too hard to read for my taste.

My questions are:

- Are we understanding the recommendations correctly (to use normalization and selectors)?
- Is using a map the correct way to process our data and show it in the view or is there a better way? I am asking because this basically copies our data (slightly modified) many times into the props of our React components
- Is there a nicer way to do this mapping (which is basically a SQL like join)? Because I really don't like this imperative approach and would find a functional one much nicer.